# twitter bootstrap as our "go to" framework?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, blueprint-css

We've been using html5 boilerplate with blueprint css for the last couple of projects. With some tweaks, we were able to make blueprint "responsive". We like blueprint, but are concerned it may be a bit "dated", from what little we know about gui trends. We've been hearing a lot of buzz about twitter bootstrap 2.0. From what we saw, we liked bootstrap's simplicity and the fact that it provides responsiveness out of the box. However, we're concerned that it's too heavy-duty for our purposes.

So, what I'm wondering is:

We know the look of bootstrap can be customized without limit. But, is it more work than it's worth
to completely overhaul the default look and feel of the framework? (Our designers will never design web apps/sites based on bootstrap).

Also, I'd love to hear about what experiences, in general, other people have had with switching from blueprint to bootstrap.

Comment: I hope you don't care about semicolons in your javascript... :-)

Comment: Good question, I think its a matter of taste. If you want some more freedom maybe you could take a look at http://foundation.zurb.com

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents:

I am a fan of twitter bootstrap. I've used it for an internal application at work. I basically used it to convert a ordinary looking application to a responsive application with a much needed user-friendly user interface.

I did make some customisations to the default twitter bootstrap css library. I did not find this particularly difficult, and neither should a developer/designer if they know their way around html/css/browser web dev tool.

I think it is designed well enough for a developer/designer to still have some serious gains even after making their customisations.